# how to draw high-speed diagonal lines in windows?

Tags: performance, graphics, 2d

I need to visualize a design in windows application, and therefore need to draw diagonal lines very fast. I tried to work with GDI+ (because I need transparency) and the speed of diagonal lines is about 10 times slower than to draw vertical/horizontal lines. I need sometimes about 400ms to draw 2000 diagonals that cross the screen.

After this I tested Direct2D, and this was about 2x faster than GDI+, but way not fast enough. Now I am starting to look at OpenGL to draw 2D graphics. There I would look from above at the scene and use an orthogonal projection.

Can anybody tell me, what the right way is to draw high-speed diagonals?

Regards, Pete

Comment: If you are willing to sacrifice quality for performance, you could try to rasterize them yourself? I mean, is the performance really that bad? What's your setup? What language? Are you creating/destroying too many objects? Show us your code.

Answer (score 0):

You could manually rasterize the lines to a pixel buffer (simply a 2D integer array), preferably in a faster language (e.g. externall DLL in C), then *blit* the buffer as a bitmap to your window (GDI or DirectDraw are sufficient).

A good procedure for this would be *Brensenham's line algorithm*: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm.

If you need anti-aliasing: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xiaolin_Wu%27s_line_algorithm.

---

I used this method for a software renderer project, and achieved a x2 performance increase (as you did with Direct2D, but I'm still using GDI+) when I migrated from VB.NET to C. I was able to get 40+ FPS at 800x600 on an old 1.7 GHz Pentium machine, and ~25 even with GDI+, so I'm not sure why performance is inadequate in your case.

Comment: I am accessing GDI+ from Delphi, so the speed is mostly like working in C/C++. I forgot to mention that I am using custom dashed lines, which decreases the performance dramatically. I can draw about 10k solid lines in about 100ms, but that is not enough. With greater designs I have about 1 million diagonals, that should be zoomable with 20fps. So I need to draw about 1 million lines in about 50ms.

Comment: @PeterS well GDI+ is quite inefficient compared to drawing the lines yourself (just take a look at the call stack). If needs must you can even migrate the inner loop to assembly (IDK about Delphi but that's possible in C/C++)

Answer (score 0):

For highest performance use OpenGL or Direct3D.  You'll be able to take advantage of hardware accelerated drawing at the expense of more code to get things set up.  You should be able to draw tens of thousands of lines in <16ms easily.